# How to get value from Future<MyObject> in java Rest API

Tags: java, rest

Part of my Rest Client code:

```
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("username", "abc").param("password", "123");     

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://abc/abc.exe/api/v1/auth");

    Future<OTCSTicket> ticket = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .buildPost(Entity.form(form)).submit(OTCSTicket.class);

    try {
        System.out.println(ticket.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How to get the value inside the OTCSTicket object?

Or is there another way I can do to accept the json response from the rest web service and map it to my OTCSTicket class?

I'm a newbie..:)

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: to authenticate, send username & password using form, web service will return ticket upon successful authentication. web service will return ticket in json format, and i want to map it to my OTCSTicket class

Comment: so, where does Future came into the picture ? It has to be Response or ClientResponse

Comment: coz this statement: target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .buildPost(Entity.form(form)).submit(OTCSTicket.class); returns the Future type

Comment: which documentation are following share it here I will have a look

Comment: Maybe u can recommend the statements I should use to achieve what I'm trying to achieve, if u were in my place..

Comment: The reason why I asked is, to make sure, you don't need to make lot change instead make changes to your existing code. Also, to understand whether you are following authentic resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ticket.get()` to get the value. This is a blocking call.

You can also use `ticket.get(timeout, unit)` for non-blocking call which times out after timeout units.

Comment: got this error:

No message body reader has been found for class com.abc.importer.model.OTCSTicket, ContentType: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: You can may be get a string response by using `Future<String>` and then convert String to Java Object by using a parser like Jackson?